# Склонение географических названий

Tags: склонение

Как правильно написать в официальном документе: *Администрация посёлка Подкумок* или *Администрация посёлка Подкумка*?
По всем правилам, вроде бы, нужно выбрать второй вариант. Но тут на Ставрополье такой косноязычный народ, что повсеместно используют первый. И правильный вариант всем царапает слух. Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С точки зрения норм русского языка правильно *посёлка Подкумка*, а следовать этим нормам или нет, вопрос скорее этический. Сам был в подобной ситуации, когда в армии комнату досУга и отдыха военнослужащих все упорно именовали "комнатой дОсуга".